# PHP Slim post route to MySql not working

Tags: php, slim

After following this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/odan/d2b889c350aa2ea0ff8e5ca93ce588a2): I now have a Slim environment. I can get my data from MySql, but I just can't post. I have tried something like this:

```
...
$app->post('/someRoute', function (Request $request, Response $response){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO someTable(firstName, lastName)
            VALUES(:FN, :LN)";


    $db = $this->get(Connection::class);
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    //$rows = $db->table('someTable')->get();

    $stmt->bindParam(':FN', $request->getParam('FN'));
    $stmt->bindParam(':LN', $request->getParam('LN'));

    $stmt->execute();   

});
```

This does not work, but I can't see where the error might be because I don't know how to debug a POST function with `HTML/PHP`. My app send's the parameters to the function just fine. I don't have a lot of experience with server-side programming, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @LeeH. This line `$db = $this->get(Connection::class);` should return a Illuminate database connection and not a `PDO` object. To get the PDO object try: `$db = $this->get(\PDO::class);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use a query builder instead of my own SQL statements. Sorted

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the PDO class, you can "TryCatch" it:

```
try 
{
  // Your code
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  // Error Message
  print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```